# Print from c++ file running on postgresql

Tags: c++, c, postgresql

I am running some C++ code in postgresql. I am trying to print some output to keep track of the execution, but no result. Is there anything I need to add somewhere to enable `printf` command to work? I am adding the below mentioned files in my code:

```
#include "postgres.h"

#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
```

What I am trying to print:

```
printf("abc");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been trying to get some output for the past 2 days. Thanks!

**Edit** : I am running the postgresql server using SSH. Let me know via comments if any more information is needed.

Comment: Printf works for C++ as well.

Comment: Try `printf("abc\n");`

Comment: yes, trying now. Let u know soon.

Comment: Nope. No output either. Is there any settings that have to be changed in postgresql to enable output to screen?

Comment: check `/var/log/postgresql.log` or a similar log file for the string `abc`... if you are running from a stored procedure, that's where the server log is going (probably)...

Comment: The best references for PostgreSQL C programming is the manual, and if you can't find it documented, the source code. The sources are really pretty sane to read and search; find an example that does what you want and look up the comments on the definitions for the functions it calls. (`cstags -R -b` or `ctags -R` and `vim -t` are your friends). BTW, it should not be C++, just pure C; writing C++ inside PostgreSQL is extremely hard to get right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use PostgreSQL's build-in logging system: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/error-message-reporting.html

From the reference:

```
elog(INFO, "count=%d", count);
```

The log level has to match the level you've configured PostgreSQL to write to its log file.

Comment: `elog` is fine for debug tracing, etc. For production quality code that's meant to produce quality error messages, `ereport` is often preferable.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("abc");` will try to write to `stdout`, but normally Postgresql server runs as a daemon, which means it will close `stdout`, that is why you cannot see that string at the standard output.

You should use [the error report facilities](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/error-message-reporting.html) offered by Postgresql to output those message to Postgresql log file, as pointed out by @rygvis.

Comment: Depending on the server startup, stderr (as opposed to stdout) often goes to the server log file. But it's much, much, much better to use `elog` and `ereport`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fprintf(stderr, "abc\n"); instead of printf("abc");